# Bathroom sink overflow clogged

Tags: sink

Once when a bathroom sink drain is cleared so that it drains properly, would that also take care of the sink overflow slots at the top??

Answer (score 1):

Normally the overflows do not plug up so it should have cleared the problem. the Best way to find out is plug the basin and fill until it is draining into the overflows. If it doesn't back up in a few seconds after starting to run in the overflow your system is working properly.